# I wonder if "for passengers to board Flight 139 at Gate 57" could be divided intensively?

Tags: attributives

I have checked some material which says "for somebody to do something" is a compound structure used to be attribute such as "It’s time for everybody to go to bed." So in this example:

> This is the last call for passengers to board Flight 139 at Gate 57.

**this** is the subject;

**is** is the predicate;

**the last call** is the predicative or complement for subject;

and **for passengers to board Flight 139 at Gate 57** is the attributive.

---

**Is that right?** and I wonder if "for passengers to board Flight 139 at Gate 57" could be divided intensively?

Comment: What do you mean by *divided intensively*?

Comment: it means divided at a lower level. such as "for passengers / to board Flight 139 / at Gate 57" what's their members specifically?

Comment: divided intensively I mean divided further, gosh, such a simple was off my mind !